# missing rrsensorapi.h for gathering sensor data from N97 Nokia device

Tags: symbian, nokia, sensors

I am quite new with symbian and c++. I try to use sensor on N97 device. I got error that rrsensorapi.h is not found. I have check through epoc folder it not there either. In this case, how can I find rrsensorapi?

I have sensor.pri file like this

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$APP_LAYER_SYSTEMINCLUDE

HEADERS += xqsensor.h \
    xqaccsensor.h \
    xqdeviceorientation.h \
    xqdeviceorientation_p.h

SOURCES += xqsensor.cpp \
    xqaccsensor.cpp \
    xqdeviceorientation.cpp \
    xqdeviceorientation_p.cpp

  exists($${EPOCROOT}epoc32/release/winscw/udeb/RRSensorApi.lib)| \
    exists($${EPOCROOT}epoc32/release/armv5/lib/RRSensorApi.lib) {
        message( "Building for Sensor plugin" )

    DEPENDPATH += .\plugin

    HEADERS += xqsensor_p.h \
        xqaccsensor_p.h

    SOURCES += xqsensor_p.cpp \
        xqaccsensor_p.cpp

    symbian:LIBS += -lRRSensorApi
    } else {
        message("Warning: Sensor API not found!")

    }
```

Comment: Are you building for device or emulator when the error happens?

Answer (score 0):

As quoted on the Forum Nokia Discussions website, the RRSensorAPI works only with SOME S60 3rd  Edition FP1 devices... Info [here](http://www.forum.nokia.com/forum/showpost.php?p=591379&postcount=2).

The API's for sensors on S60v5 have been changed... To solve your question of using sensors with the N97 (S60 5th Edition), refer to [this](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Nokia_Sensor_APIs) wiki document on Forum Nokia.

Hope this helps...